# Encouraging helpful edits

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

I think that currently there is no real incentive for people to correct mistakes in their questions/answers, as downvotes tend to persist (as do upvotes).

In my original question I gave an example where I got downvoted and as a result fixed my answer, but the downvote remained. Of course this could be due to a variety of reasons: the voter haven't looked at the revised answer, my correction could be wrong, etc.

The thing is, that no matter the reason for the downvote, there is no clear feedback of the fix. Without that feedback I cannot tell if I did well or not. For future viewers of the question they might skip a potentially correct answer just because it still has a low score, and my effort would be in vain.

My suggestion is to grey out scores of questions/answers that received an update, so it will be clearer that the score doesn't necessarily reflect the current content of the post. The score can become black again once all voters of the previous revision have reviewed the question (while keeping the review voluntary, maybe encourage it with e.g. a badge for revisiting X edits).

The benefit I see in this is double:

- Viewers will be less likely to rule out edited posts (after all, if someone cares to fix their mistakes we have good reason to believe they act to good purpose)
- I get acknowledged of my correction and it doesn't go unseen, thus I may be more inclined to correct future mistakes.

I believe this will encourage more people to edit their posts, because everyone makes mistakes every now and then.
On a side note I think that we shouldn't be harsh on people that don't present themselves clearly on the first time, because we can't always tell the effort that was put on their side, and letting people the chance to correct themselves is an opportunity to also share their knowledge.

Comment: If questions would just start in a closed state and require votes to approve and open them, I'd feel much less need to downvote things.

Comment: I can't disagree with your point, that the reputational status of a question should reflect the utility of its current state, but what specific changes to the site dynamics are you suggesting to help implement this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: but we don't have enough site members willing to moderate content as it is

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and as I keep saying when people point that out, it isn't a problem if good questions sit closed for a while. There's no sense of urgency here, after all. (Perhaps gold-tags who also propose to write an answer, could reopen unilaterally, under such a scheme...)

Comment: "_If questions would just start in a closed state and require votes to approve and open them_" I guess the staging ground would improve things a bit in that area @KarlKnechtel

Comment: The title is "_Encouraging helpful edits_" but we seem to be talking about getting downvoters to revisit or somehow reflect that their votes are stale? How does this encourage helpful edits?

Comment: We can’t have nice things; it’s proven time and time again if someone provides feedback they will be attacked by the individual who ask the question when that individual disagrees with that feedback.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat suppose I fix a post of mine and it's now correct. Because the post still has a negative score there is no incentive for me to fix the issue: future viewers might skip the post because of its low score, and I won't be rewarded for my effort.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suggest to grey out scores given to edited answers/questions/comments when voters haven't revisited the post since the last edit.

Comment: SE is currently doing work in this area. Please see [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground).

Comment: @towel the idea is that you spend enough effort that you get it right the first time, otherwise you're asking other people to do it for you. Do you think people really want to have to do that? That's one human nature reason why poor quality posts are downvoted. So I suggest putting more effort into the original version of your question, you can have as much time as you wish to polish it till it's perfect. After all, the downvoter isn't going to get the time back that they spent trying to understand your question before you edited it into shape are they?

Comment: @RobertLongson you assume I don't put enough effort in the first place, when in fact different people tend to see the same subject in different ways, and all the effort I can muster won't help me see beyond my own perspective. There is no problem in the voter having no time to review my question, but I think there needs to be some way to tell others that the score might not reflect the current content of the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound sorry to hear that. Perhaps the solution lies more in the social domain than the technological one :)

Comment: Ok, I rephrased the question. Now I think its title and body are more in line with each other.

Comment: The only thing that people other than you can do is edit grammar and spelling. That leaves your question fundamentally the same post other people's edits so the votes should stand, especially if as you say it's as good as you can make it from day 1.

Comment: You may want to clarify how results of "hide negative vote count" experiment solved with your proposal. Also explaining how hiding score after random edit "encourages helpful edits" may be nice.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I never mentioned hiding negative votes - my suggestion was to communicate to viewers that the current score hasn't been verified yet against the new changes. Also I wrote that greying out the score will give feedback to the editor, thus encouraging helpful edits, because from my (limited) experience every time I corrected a post there was no change to its score.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't think people get attacked for making constructive criticism, unless the attacker believes they also downvoted. A simple modification to the system software could change that...

Comment: @PM2Ring you're right - I removed the comments from the question. Unfortunately I think this question is pretty done though -- there's an overwhelmingly negative response to it so I'd be better off closing it (and think twice before I ever fancy suggesting another idea)

Comment: @towel Don't worry about it. Votes here on MSO don't affect your rep. And downvotes don't *necessarily* imply that people think your question / answer is bad, they can also indicate that people disagree with what you're saying.

Comment: IMHO, you've made some interesting points that are worth discussing. OTOH, some of this stuff has been discussed to death, which tends to attract downvotes. But currently, there are no close votes.

Comment: As the old saying goes, you don't get a second chance to make a first impression. Too many questions are posted in a bad state, with typos, bad grammar, and poor structure. A lot of that should be fixed *before* the question is posted.

Comment: Sure, we'd like to encourage people to edit their posts in response to feedback, and to encourage down / close voters to re-visit posts after they've been edited. A lot of us Follow posts that we down / close vote if we think the post has a chance of being improved. But if the post is of very low quality I'm unlikely to follow it because  I know that it's unlikely to be improved.

Comment: *"I gave an example where I got downvoted"* - Freudian slip... or admittance that you take downvotes personally?

Comment: @Gimby taking the question to personal levels is below us - I wanted to feel good for correcting my posts. The downvotes made it clear that people see my suggestion differently, so I moved on (and yes, reconsider posting questions here as you can't ever satisfy everyone).
Besides, having that itch to correct the post because of the downvotes isn't all that bad :) (as long as you don't actually think there is a personal vendetta against you)

Comment: You may want to browse through [these search results for `edit notify downvoter`](/search?tab=votes&q=edit%20notify%20downvoter) if you haven't already. See also this very popular feature-request on MSE: [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: "I think I've fixed the issue now - please check"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/997587)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel your "pain" too. I also would like to have have "pain relief" for it, but I don't think that greying out the score is necessary, because the post already has a card showing the timestamp and the user avatar indicating that the post was edited. Also edited posts are bumped in the Active tab.

---

I think that part of what you are trying to say is that:

1. People should be able to easily see the vote summary (score) of the post's last revision.
2. This will be benefical for viewers.
3. This will encourage people to make helpful edits.

At this time, each post has a button that shows the post's timeline which could hide/show the *vote summaries*. These *vote summaries* are grouped by day, not by revision. It will be nice to have *vote summaries* by revision, and I think that it should not be very difficult. Maybe this could be done using browser extension/userscript.

What I do not yet a have a clear idea for yet are:

1. Not all the edits are significant enough to request a vote summary review/new vote summary. How will it be determined when it is necessary to do a "vote summary review"/have a new vote summary?
2. How to show the vote summary of the last revision on the question page.
3. How to sort posts using the vote summary of the last revision.

Comment: 1. I don't think there's a good way to determine that. Sometimes all that you need to fix a comment it a single character, so it will probably be best to leave that voluntary.

Comment: 2. Sorry, I couldn't think of another way besides greying out the previous score.
3. I don't have a good answer for that because it depends on whether rating or activity is prioritized when sorting. Leaving the current sorting without change is probably better as it will prevent confusion.

Comment: @towel Any change around this to the system looks to be complex. I think that the best that could be done in the short term is to take advange of the edit summary, i.e. to include the vote summary, add a keyword or use some sort of semantic versioning, then very selectively ask for attention, i.e. in a chat room with people willing to help to improve posts or be bold and post a question on Meta taking risk of the Meta effect.